# Tagging a user in a wall post/update using Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I'm using stream.publish to write to the user's wall and attempted to get "@ tagging" to work but with no avail.

If the user's name is Fred and his uid is 1234, I tried sending over "@Fred", "@1234", "@[1234]", "@[Fred]", etc. and couldn't get it to work. The raw string would display every time.

Can someone confirm if this is possible with the API or not? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing in my application. Using @[friend_uid:1:custom_text, f.ex friend name] shows a link to your friend, but It still won't show up as a tag. The friend won't get a notification. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct syntax is

@[user_id:1:name]

it shows as a tag, but it doesn't trigger a notification. Anyone knows why?

Comment: How is this syntax is used? E.g how will you tag 3 people, and include a message with it? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying this code: `$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
            'name'    => 'TEST NAME',
            'caption' => 'Test Caption',
            'description' => 'Test Description',
            'message' => '@[xxxxx:1:test]',
            'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
        ));` but this simply posts a status saying 'test' without taggiing my friend or showing any notification

Comment: Same, as far as I know, it is FB bug.

Comment: @Guy Is there any documentation that describes this method of tagging people? If so whats the url?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need follow this: NOTE: You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

You need to specify a place with the fan page ID of the location associated with the post.
more… https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Answer (score 0):

**reese**:

@[user_id:1:name] - It will replace it with the 'name'  which you have given

@[user_id:0] - This will notify the user BUT it will happen when you MANUALLY typing it in wall or comment section NOT through graph api, say for eg., if you want to notify this user @[user_id:0] so you are appending this text in message parameter of https://graph.facebook.com/feed api it won't work, I hope you understand :)