# Tagging people in a Facebook Post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you press @ when typing a status on facebook.com, you can type a friends' name and have him tagged in your facebook status.

How can friends be tagged when making a wall post using facebook connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to tag another user or page via the API as a user can. Interestingly, when you query the API for a tagged post you can see a syntax that indicates a user is tagged, but using that syntax and posting to the API doesn't result in a tag.

I think this is done to prevent applications from gaming users' notifications: if you could make a post and tag a bunch of people programmatically, you'd in effect be spamming those users with notifications.

Comment: What do you think about the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099183/tagging-a-user-in-a-wall-post-update-using-facebook-api/4776656#4776656 , will that work?

Comment: I've tried that method in the past with no luck (the raw text gets posted and is not converted to a tag). That's not to say it doesn't work now though. I'll try it when I have a moment.

Answer (score 4):

the checkin API has a way to tag people I don't know if that is possible for wall posts

```
 curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=The coffee is just meh.' \
 -F 'place=PAGE_ID' \
 -F 'coordinates={"latitude":"...", "longitude": "..."}' \
 -F 'tags=USER_ID1, USER_ID2' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

and I remember seeing a spam application that tagged users friends on wall posts so I think it is possible but not documented. I'll try to find the wall post and link a screenshot here.

Comment: i am trying to hack a method myself.  I seen it was possible, someone using php-sdk, i am trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this method:

```
$url_params = array(
    'formatting' => 'MARKDOWN',
    'message' => $message
);
$params = http_build_query($url_params);
$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' . $params);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$rest = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
```

and in the message I have (among others):

```
$message .= '**Tagged person** : @[' . $id . ']';
```

the id has to be the numeric id of the facebook account - name or email won't do.