# how to tag users in application post of a facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

can anyone please tell me how to tag user's friend in a wall post made by my app on user's wall. 
say bob is a friend of emily. 
i have an application that, tells all the friends name starting with e. now when i make a post on bob's wall :
"hey bob emily i your friend whose name starts with e"
i want emily to be tagged.

Please let me know how to do it.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the name of the users in the message to become links to their profile, use :
@ in front of their FULL name with no space after the at symbol.

for John Smith, it would be @John Smith

Is that what you want ?

---

**Update :** It seems not possible using the graph api right now. Only manually.

See : [Tagging people in a Facebook Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507430/tagging-people-in-a-facebook-post)

And : http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-tag-a-Facebook-user-via-the-Facebook-Graph-API

---

**Update 2:** It is definitively not (yet) possible through facebook api's.

There are tickets about this in facebook bug tracker :

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12074

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13174

Comment: well i donot agree there are apps, which tag your friend http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=193426267357770

Comment: next time, before answering please make sure what you answer, thanks!!

Comment: yep sorry but there is conflicting information about that on the web and nothing in facebook documentation about that

Comment: Actually YOU should verify your information, your application does permit you to tag a picture. But here we are talking about tagging @username in a wall post. I tried it myself and it does NOT work using the API, you have feature requests/bug tickets [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12074) and [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13174) on Facebook Bug Tracker about it