# When posting to my FB wall with Open Graph is it possible to @mention smb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebooker

Can I @mention somebody when posting to my wall with Facebook Open Graph?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this isn't possible or supported via the Graph API. [Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099183/tagging-a-user-in-a-wall-post-update-using-facebook-api) seem to have unearthed some of that functionality, but I wasn't able to repeat it in the testing I just did.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the tagging feature isn't currently available via any of Facebook's APIs.