# Tag friends on a feed post with php facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, tags, publish

I'm 4 hours tring to send a post on a page on facebook with

```
$attachment = array(
        'message' => "@[".$id.":1:".$name.'] dsf sadfewqr',
                    'name' => "test test etst etst test test",
                    'link' => "http://www.tiscali.it",
                    'description' => "test",
        'picture'=> "http://www.example.com/img.jpg",
        'message_tags' => array(
            'data' => array(
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $partecipant['name_screen'],
                'offset' => 0,
                "type" => "user",
                'length' => strlen($name)
            )
        ),
        'access_token' => '--fanpageaccesstoken--'
    );

    $facebook->api('/'.$idfanpage.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Every time i get only message without tag. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get the message_tags parameter from?

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts you should use the *tags* parameter to give a list of comma separated user ids.

And pay attention to the note saying, *You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.*

Comment: I made ​​a mistake using the reading parameters. And how can i use tags within the message? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Do you actually mean tagging in the sense of saying you were at some place with other people, or do just mean mentioning someone in a post, as you can do on facebook by starting to type @username? The latter is obviously not possible via the API, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099183/tagging-a-user-in-a-wall-post-update-using-facebook-api/4776656